# C malloc (Segmentation fault: 11)

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, malloc

I'm trying to understand malloc but I keep getting "Segmentation fault: 11" with this piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char ** ptr = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*));

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            ptr[i][j] = 'a';

        printf("%s\n", ptr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I thought there wasn't enough bytes being allocated so I did `malloc(sizeof(char*) * 100`, but gives me the same error. What am I not understanding here?

Comment: `ptr[i]` is a pointer, but what does it point to ?

Comment: Does it not point to the beginning of the memory allocated? If I just do `char * ptr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char))` and take away the second loop statement, it works fine.

Comment: `ptr` does, but `ptr[0]` does not.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: @Olaf What do you mean do not cast? I don't understand.

Comment: You cast (the result of) `malloc`, so you should know what a (type)cast is.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: Oh ok, I see. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you allocate a 2D array, you need to allocate the individual sub-arrays as well. In addition, you need to say how many elements you wish to have. For that you multiply the desired count by the number of elements, like this:

```
char ** ptr = (char **) malloc(5*sizeof(char*));
// Size=5 ---------------------^
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    ptr[i] = malloc(11*sizeof(char));
    // sizeof(char) is always 1, so the multiplication above is redundant.
    // You need 11 elements for ten characters
    for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        ptr[i][j] = 'a';
    }
    // don't forget to null-terminate the string:
    ptr[i][10] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", ptr[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is totally messed up in every aspect!

1) you allocated memory for exactly 1 Pointer to it. This means you can access ptr[0], but not ptr[1] ... ptr[4] as you are trying to do.

2) you never allocate anything for the elements in ptr[i].

3) you try to print a string a ptr[i] which is (even if your allocation would be right) never terminated.

4) although this is obviously only a beginners test, never forget to free your memory!!!!

To reach something CLOSE to what your sampel code is describing you could do:

```
int main() 
{
int i,j;
char ** ptr = malloc( 5 * sizeof(char*) ); /* an array of 5 elements of type char* */
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    ptr[i] =  malloc( 11*sizeof(char) ); /* The element i of the array is an array of 11 chars (10 for the 'a' character, one for the null-termination */
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        ptr[i][j] = 'a';
    ptr[i][10] = '\0'; /* strings need to be null terminated */

    printf("%s\n", ptr[i]);
}
// free your memory!
for (i=0; i<5; i++ )
{
    free(ptr[i]);
}
free(ptr);

return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, never knew about `free()`. I should use it once I'm done using any pointer initialized with malloc?

Comment: malloc "reserves" memory. If you don't free it, your program uses more and more memory, never giving it back to the operating system. Every "malloc()" should have a matching "free()" somewhere in the code. Also this isn't a real problem in your code, because the memory is released anyways as soon as the program terminates, you should learn this practice IMMEDIATELY. Whenever you call malloc, you should have a matching free. What/Where "matching" is depends on your code.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you for all the info!

Comment: He cannot read through `ptr[0]` either as he has not initialized it. He allocated memory for lots of pointers but did not make them point anywhere.

Comment: @MarcoFreudenberger No, this answer says "This means you can access ptr[0], but not ptr[1] ... ptr[4] as you are trying to do." which is wrong.

Comment: Original code: char ** ptr = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*)); So he assigns an array with exactly one char*. This allows to access ptr[0]. He can't, though, access chars at ptr[0][...], because the value of the element at ptr[0] is not yet set to anything meaningful.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to allocate the memory is:

```
char (*ptr)[11] = malloc( sizeof(char[5][11]) );

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        ptr[i][j] = 'a';

    ptr[i][10] = 0;
    printf("%s\n", ptr[i]);
}

free(ptr);
```

It seems less hassle to use a single allocation than to use a lot of allocations, unless you have a pressing reason to do the latter.

Comment: a little oops.  declared 11 pointers to char, but only set the first one.

Comment: @user3629249 no, this is 1 pointer to an array of 11 chars. You're describing `char *ptr[11];`